# Change default orientation of LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, orientation

I always forget to define `android:orientation` property to `LinearLayout`'s in my layout-resources. Because of default value of layout's orientation (horizontal) I spent a little of time every time I forget about it.
Is there a way to override default orientation of `LinearLayout` (btw, I don't want to use custom view) in whole application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also having same problem of every time writing that same line.

> There are two ways you can do it:
>
> 1. Create **CustomLayout** which will extend LinearLayout. [which you and
>      me also don't prefer].
> 2. Create **Live Template** - A cool feature of Android
>      Studio.

### Going for 2nd one(a preferred one):

1. Open Settings in Android Studio by **File > Settings** OR **Ctrl+Alt+S**
2. Navigate to **Editor > Live Templates**

[image: Navigate to Editor]

4. Click on Add button on [image: ADD] right side. And select **Live Template**
5. As we are creating template for **XML**, define applicable context as XML Text [image]
6. Now fill details:
   Abbreviation name will be your short name. Description is optional. Fill template text as this:
   [image]
   [you can set height or width as whatever you prefer]
7. Click **DONE**. That's it.

### Usage:

Open any Layout xml file. And in Editor, just write your abbreviation which we set earlier.[you can also list out all available live templates by pressing **Ctrl+J**]
You will see a hint:
[image]

Just click on that, and there you go.
Your template text will be here:
[image]

[**NOTE:** In template text I have used **$END$**, which means after applying code text, the cursor will be placed at this point. For more Live template variables, please have a look at this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/live-template-variables.html)]

For more cool details about Live Templates: [LINK](https://medium.com/google-developers/writing-more-code-by-writing-less-code-with-android-studio-live-templates-244f648d17c7#.v82q1gpgg)

Hope, this will help you. You can also create lots of own Live Templates to make life easier. :)

Comment: it's good solution, also nice introducing to live templates, thank you

Answer (score 0):

if we create our own custom Linear Layout then it is compulsory to define it's orientation during coding of that layout. Otherwise it may be rise an error for it.